# convert an imagen to tiff format with transparent backgroung using python

Tags: python, background, jpeg, tiff, transparent

I would like to convert an imagen with jpg format to tiff format. However, I would like to have the figure with a transparent background. I have some pictures like this

[image]

I found this script to help me but...

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

threshold=100
dist=5
img=Image.open("picture.jpg").convert('RGBA')
# np.asarray(img) is read only. Wrap it in np.array to make it modifiable.
arr=np.array(np.asarray(img))
r,g,b,a=np.rollaxis(arr,axis=-1)
mask=((r>threshold)
      & (g>threshold)
      & (b>threshold)
      & (np.abs(r-g)<dist)
      & (np.abs(r-b)<dist)
      & (np.abs(g-b)<dist)
      )
arr[mask,3]=0
img=Image.fromarray(arr,mode='RGBA')
img.save('out.png')
img.save('out.tiff')
```

but the result is that:

[image]

The imagen expected is just the grey and red region (balls and sticks) with the background transparent. Like the example, if I put the imagen wherever, it doesn't see the white region.

[image]

[image]

Thanks for your help and support

Comment: what is your expected output? How should image look like?

Comment: Sure, the goal is have a transparent background, just to have the grey and red region (balls and sticks). I have put an example of imagen expected. Thanks